# How do I loop over files individually?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

This part of code adds up all the times a word exists throughout all my .txt files:

```
def wordcounts():
word_frequencies = dict()
totaal = dict()
for bestand in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    word_list = clean_text(bestand)
    for i in word_list:
        if i in word_frequencies:
            word_frequencies[i] += 1
        else:
            word_frequencies[i] = 1
totaal[bestand] = word_frequencies
return totaal
```

The output is:

```
{'test3.txt': {'aap': 4, 'mies': 4, 'wim': 1, 'noot': 2}}
```

The output I need is:

```
{'test1.txt': {'aap': 1, 'noot': 1, 'mies': 1}, 'test2.txt': {'aap': 1, 'noot': 1}, 'test3.txt': {'aap': 1, 'mies': 2}, 'test4.txt': {'aap': 1, 'mies': 1, 'wim': 1}}
```

Does anyone have an idea what I need to do to make sure it does this for each file individual?

(clean_text() is a function I made to process .txt files)

Comment: All your needed counts are one.  Does that mean you only would one for words that appear in the file as opposed to an actual count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you have the result dictionary (totaal) sitting outside of the for loop

```
def wordcounts():
    word_frequencies = dict()
    totaal = dict()
    for bestand in glob.glob('*.txt'):
        word_list = clean_text(bestand)
        for i in word_list:
            if i in word_frequencies:
                word_frequencies[i] += 1
            else:
                word_frequencies[i] = 1
    totaal[bestand] = word_frequencies
    return totaal
```

So what's happening is you're loading totaal with one key (the final bestand) and loading it with all the word_frequencies.

If you indent the totaal line to be included in the for loop, it will populate the dictionary with a key for each bestand, like you expected.

You'll also want to move word_frequencies inside the loop, so that you only get the frequencies for each bestand:

```
def wordcounts():
    totaal = dict()
    for bestand in glob.glob('*.txt'):
        # MOVED WORD_FREQUENCIES HERE
        word_frequencies = dict()
        word_list = clean_text(bestand)
        for i in word_list:
            if i in word_frequencies:
                word_frequencies[i] += 1
            else: 
                word_frequencies[i] = 1
         # NOTE THAT THIS IS NOW PROPERLY INDENTED
         totaal[bestand] = word_frequencies
    return totaal
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're only missing an indent, try this:

```py
def wordcounts():
word_frequencies = dict()
totaal = dict()
for bestand in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    word_list = clean_text(bestand)
    for i in word_list:
        if i in word_frequencies:
            word_frequencies[i] += 1
        else:
            word_frequencies[i] = 1
    totaal[bestand] = word_frequencies  # < Added an indent here
return totaal
```

Comment: That solved it, also I needed to change the place where word_frequencies is created so that it would not add up all the values.